# If $|f''| < M|f '|$ and $f \sim_{+\infty} \exp$, then $f' \sim_{+\infty} \exp$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, equivalence-relations

> Let f be a $C^2$ function : $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ (i.e. the second
>   derivative is continuous). Suppose there is a constant $M > 0$ such
>   that in a neighborhood of $+\infty$, $|f''(x)| < M|f '(x)|$, and that
>   $f$ is equivalent to $\exp$ in $+\infty$. Show that $f'$ is also
>   equivalent to $\exp$ in $+\infty$.

First there exists $A$ such that $f'(x)$ $>0$ for all $x ≥ A$ or $<0$ for all $x ≥ A$, by the intermadiate value theorem.

Suppose $f' < 0$ then $f$ decreases on $[A, \infty)$, it contradicts $f \sim \exp$ in $+ \infty$.

So $f' > 0$ on $[A, \infty)$. Then assume  $|f''(x)| < M|f'(x)|$ is true on $[A, \infty)$.

$\forall x ≥A$,  $f'(x) = \int_{A}^x f''(t)dt + f'(A)$, so $|f'(x)| ≤ M\int_{A}^x f'(t)dt + f'(A)$ i.e.

|$f'(x)| ≤ M(f(x) - f(A)) + f'(A) = Mf(x) + C$

Then, consider $\exp(-x)f(x)$, we deduce from the results above, $\exp(-x)f(x) \to 1$ and $(\exp(-x)f(x))''$ is bounded in $+\infty$.

It can be shown that implies  $(\exp(-x)f(x))' \to 0$ and we conclude $f' \sim f \sim \exp$.

Does anyone have another approach ? What if $<$ was $≤$ ? Any generalization ?

Comment: Remotely related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1080590/f-underset-infty-mathcalo-bigrf-bigl-implies-that-f-underset-i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach.

**Lemma**
Let $a  <  b$, suppose that

$$1 > {\varepsilon}  \geqslant  {\sup }_\limits{x \in  \left[a , b\right]} \left|f \left(x\right) {e}^{{-x}}-1\right|$$

then there exists $c \in  (a , b)$ such that

$$\left|\frac{{f'} \left(c\right)}{f \left(c\right)}-1\right|  \leqslant  \frac{1}{b-a} \log  \left(\frac{1+{\varepsilon}}{1-{\varepsilon}}\right)$$

**Proof** We use the mean value theorem to get
a $c \in  \left(a , b\right)$ such that

$$\left(b-a\right) \frac{{f'} \left(c\right)}{f \left(c\right)} = \log  \left(f \left(b\right)\right)-\log  \left(f \left(a\right)\right) = \left(b-a\right)+\log  \left(\frac{f \left(b\right) {e}^{{-b}}}{f \left(a\right) {e}^{{-a}}}\right)$$

hence

$$\left|\frac{{f'} \left(c\right)}{f \left(c\right)}-1\right| = \frac{1}{b-a} \left|\log  \left(\frac{f \left(b\right) {e}^{{-b}}}{f \left(a\right) {e}^{{-a}}}\right)\right|  \leqslant  \frac{1}{b-a} \log  \left(\frac{1+{\varepsilon}}{1-{\varepsilon}}\right)$$
$\blacksquare$

We now choose
${\varepsilon} = {\varepsilon} \left(a\right) = {\sup }_\limits{x  \geqslant  a} \left|f \left(x\right) {e}^{{-x}}-1\right| \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{a \rightarrow  \infty } 0$,
we choose $b = a+\sqrt{{\varepsilon}}$, so that $c$ depends on $a$
with $\left|c-a\right|  \leqslant  \sqrt{\varepsilon}$ and $\frac{{f'} \left(c\right)}{f \left(c\right)} \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{a \rightarrow  \infty } 1$. We can write

$${f'} \left(a\right) {e}^{{-a}} = {{{\frac{{f'} \left(c\right)}{f \left(c\right)}}\times{\left(f \left(c\right) {e}^{{-c}}\right)}}\times{{e}^{c-a}}}\times{\exp } \left({-\int_{a}^{c}\frac{{f''} \left(t\right)}{{f'} \left(t\right)} d t}\right)$$

This is the product of four terms that tend to $1$ when
$a \rightarrow  \infty $. It follows that ${f'} \left(a\right) \sim  {e}^{a}$.